# Автотест андроид приложения

Tags: android

Всем доброго времени, появилась задача реализовать UI автотест приложения андроид и упаковать в апк файл для последующей работы с данным тестом как с приложением , то есть без подключения внешних модулей к ос андоид, при автотестировании. Интересует следующее , возможно ли данная реализация , и если да, то подскажите ресурс где можно ознакомится? Если нет, прошу уточнить почему.

Comment: Чекай robotium, доступен в git gub и play market

Comment: @АйзекАзимов спасибо за ответ, буду благодарен если подскажите хороший ресурс для ознакомления желательно с примерами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет [robotium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robotium), он устанавливается на телефон, примеры по его использованию. [Кодом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312379/examples-for-robotium). А если возникнет необходимость сделать кейсы визуально, то ставишь его на свой смартфон